# Oracle SQL: Nested sub-queries, outer are the same, inner differs

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, union

I'm in a situation where I have several sub-queries, joined by UNION, each nested with an inner sub-query. The outer sub-queries are fully identical to each other, while the inner queries differ and are unique.

Reuse of the entire outer sub-queries is cumbersome for reading and making changes, and it would be greatly beneficial if they could be defined once and reused. So this is a question about creating reusable SQL-queries, but with distinct inner sub-queries that are passed on as arguments.

For my examples, I will present a simplified case that has the same issue as my real code.

We're using Oracle SQL for our project.

Say that we have a database for a school or university, with the tables PERSON, STUDENT, GRADE and COURSE, and all are connected by FK-relationships.

I need to run a query which gathers a list, counting up the number of people once for every criteria:

- Number of students whose last name begin on the letter 'E'
- Number of students older than 20 years
- Number of people (including but not limited to students) who are female
- Number of students who passed the course "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade B or higher

**The expected outcome:**

```
  | Description                                     | Number_of_students
1 | Last names beginning with letter "E"            |  32
2 | Older than 20 years                             | 154
3 | All female persons                              | 356 
4 | Passed "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade >= B |  12
```

Below is a query which should satisfy what I need.
It consists of several sub-queries joined by UNION, and all have their own distinct inner query.

The code is far from brilliant, but that is beside the point. The real question is about drastically improving readability. The outer sub-queries have the same structure that could be re-used, but the inner ones are different.

```
SELECT * FROM
    -- 1st entry: Number of students on the last name 'E'
    (SELECT 'Last names beginning with letter "E"' AS Description, count(*) AS Number_of_students FROM 
      FROM PERSON p, STUDENT s, GRADE g, COURSE c
        WHERE p.ID = s.PERSON_ID 
        AND s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
        -- ... other complex code here

        AND p.ID IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID FROM PERSON p1, STUDENT s1 
              WHERE p1.ID = s1.PERSON_ID AND p1.LASTNAME LIKE 'E%'
        )
    )
UNION

-- 2nd entry: Number of students older than 20 years
    (SELECT 'Older than 20 years' AS Description, count(*) AS Number_of_students FROM 
      FROM PERSON p, STUDENT s, GRADE g, COURSE c
        WHERE p.ID = s.PERSON_ID 
        AND s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
        -- ... other complex code here

        AND p.ID IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT p2.ID FROM PERSON p2, STUDENT s2 
              WHERE p2.ID = s2.PERSON_ID AND p2.AGE > 20
        )
    )
UNION

-- 3rd entry: Number of female persons, including but not limited to students
    (SELECT 'All female persons' AS Description, count(*) AS Number_of_students FROM 
      FROM PERSON p, STUDENT s, GRADE g, COURSE c
        WHERE p.ID = s.PERSON_ID 
        AND s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
        -- ... other complex code here

        AND p.ID IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT p3.ID FROM PERSON p3 WHERE p3.GENDER = 'Female'
        )
    )
UNION

-- 4th entry: Students who passed the course "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade B or higher
    (SELECT 'Passed "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade >= B' AS Description, count(*) AS Number_of_students FROM 
      FROM PERSON p, STUDENT s, GRADE g, COURSE c
        WHERE p.ID = s.PERSON_ID 
        AND s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
        -- ... other complex code here

        AND p.ID IN(
          SELECT DISTINCT p4.ID FROM PERSON p4, STUDENT s4, GRADE g4 AND COURSE c4
            WHERE p4.ID = s4.PERSON_ID 
            AND s4.ID = g4.STUDENT_ID 
            AND g4.COURSE_ID = c4.ID
            AND (g4.GRADE = 'A' OR g4.GRADE = 'B')
            AND c4.COURSE_NAME = 'Intermediate Norwegian'
        )
    )
```

Like I said, the code is far from brilliant. I won't be surprised if some of you cringed at what you just read.

For instance, the entire fourth one could easily be replaced by a query where you replace the entire inner query with g.GRADE = 'A' OR 'B' and c.COURSE_NAME = 'Intermediate Norwegian'.

But like I said, that is not the point here.
Every outer sub-query has the same structure:

```
 (SELECT 'Passed "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade >= B' AS Description, count(*) AS Number_of_students FROM 
      FROM PERSON p, STUDENT s, GRADE g, COURSE c
        WHERE p.ID = s.PERSON_ID 
        AND s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
        -- ... other complex code here

        AND p.ID IN(
           -- Inner Sub-query here
        )
```

While every Sub-query has an inner one that differs from each other. Like the 1st and the 3rd one:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID FROM PERSON p1, STUDENT s1 WHERE p1.ID = s1.PERSON_ID AND p1.LASTNAME LIKE 'E%'
```

and

```
SELECT DISTINCT p3.ID FROM PERSON p3 WHERE p3.GENDER = 'Female'
```

**What I need:**

The real code I'm working with is far more complex, but has the same following issues as presented in the example above.

- The result must be a list with several numbers, each categorized by their own distinct criteria (preferably described in the first column).
- It consists of several sub-queries, joined by UNION
- Each of these sub-queries are completely identical, with the exception of an inner sub-query that completely unique, and different from the others.
- The resulting code is a huge beast, but could in theory be made far more readable if the outer code had been written only once, and reused with different inner code passed on as arguments.

I have recently come across the WITH-clause in Oracle SQL.
Something similar to this following change would be very beneficial:

```
WITH outer_sub_query AS (
   SELECT 'DESCRIPTION HERE' AS Description, count(*) AS Number_of_students FROM 
      FROM PERSON p, STUDENT s, GRADE g, COURSE c
        WHERE p.ID = s.PERSON_ID 
        AND s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
        -- ... other complex code here

        AND p.ID IN(
           -- INSERT INNER SUB-QUERY HERE
        )
)
SELECT * FROM (
    outer_sub_query -- Last Names beginning with letter 'E'
    UNION 
    outer_sub_query -- Age > 20
    UNION 
    outer_sub_query -- All female
    UNION 
    outer_sub_query -- Passed that course with grade >= B
)
```

Unfortunately, my needs are not yet satisfied. I still need to pass on the inner sub-queries, as well as descriptions. Something similar to this:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    outer_sub_query(
        'Last names beginning with letter "E",'
        SELECT DISTINCT p1.ID FROM PERSON p1, STUDENT s1 
          WHERE p1.ID = s1.PERSON_ID AND p1.LASTNAME LIKE 'E%'
    )
    UNION 
    outer_sub_query(
        'Older than 20 years.'
        SELECT DISTINCT p2.ID FROM PERSON p2, STUDENT s2 
          WHERE p2.ID = s2.PERSON_ID AND p2.AGE > 20
    )
    UNION 
    outer_sub_query(
        'All female persons'
        SELECT DISTINCT p3.ID FROM PERSON p3 WHERE p3.GENDER = 'Female'
    )
    UNION 
    outer_sub_query(
        'Passed "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade >= B'
        SELECT DISTINCT p4.ID FROM PERSON p4, STUDENT s4, GRADE g4 AND COURSE c4
        WHERE p4.ID = s4.PERSON_ID 
        AND s4.ID = g4.STUDENT_ID 
        AND g4.COURSE_ID = c4.ID
        AND (g4.GRADE = 'A' OR g4.GRADE = 'B')
        AND c4.COURSE_NAME = 'Intermediate Norwegian'
    )
)
```

**The questions:**

Now, defining a FUNCTION easily comes to mind. But it still brings me some questions:

- It first glance, it seems that WITH-clause does not take in parameters that can be passed on. Is there any other pre-existing clauses or functions in SQL or Oracle SQL that handles this?
- Is it possible to extract the inner sub-query out from the outer one, and still achieve the same result? (Remember: No changes in the outer sub-query itself).
- If I am to define a FUNCTION that handles this, is it possible to pass on pure SQL-codes like I have done above?
- Is there any other smart solutions that I am missing?

Thank you for your advice(s).

Comment: Guys, seriously??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common table expression (such as you already suggested) seems a likely approach for reducing code duplication in your case, but you're trying to get it to do too much for you.  CTEs cannot be parameterized in the way you hope; if they were, then a use such as you envision would no longer have them in common.

Yes, you could write a table-valued function, but that seems way overkill, and it could well be difficult for the query planner to analyze.  Here's about as far as you can go with a CTE:

```
WITH student_grades AS (
 SELECT
   p.id AS id,
   p.lastname AS lastname,
   p.age AS age,
   p.gender AS gender,
   c.course_name AS course_name,
   g.grade AS grade
 FROM
   -- You really, really should use ANSI JOIN syntax:
   PERSON p
   JOIN STUDENT s ON p.ID = s.PERSON_ID
   JOIN GRADE g   ON s.ID = g.STUDENT_ID 
   JOIN COURSE c  ON g.COURSE_ID = c.ID
   -- WHERE ... other complex code here
)
```

You might then continue your query with ...

```
-- 1st entry: Number of students on the last name 'E'
SELECT
  'Last names beginning with letter "E"' AS Description,
  count(distinct sg1.id) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_grades sg1
WHERE sg1.lastname LIKE 'E%'

UNION

-- 2nd entry: Number of students older than 20 years
SELECT
  'Older than 20 years' AS Description,
  count(distinct sg2.id) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_grades sg2
WHERE sg2.AGE > 20

UNION

-- 3rd entry: Number of female persons, including but not limited to students
-- NOTE: THIS ONE MATCHES YOUR ORIGINAL, WHICH IS INCORRECT
SELECT
  'All female persons' AS Description,
  count(distinct sg3.id) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_grades sg3
WHERE sg3.GENDER = 'Female'

UNION

-- 4th entry: Students who passed the course "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade B or higher
SELECT
  'Passed "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade >= B' AS Description,
  count(distinct sg4.id) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_grades sg4
WHERE
  sg4.COURSE_NAME = 'Intermediate Norwegian'
  AND sg4.grade IN ('A', 'B')
```

And that's actually a significant improvement.  Note in particular that you don't need to pass conditions, subquery or not, *into* the CTE; instead, you *query* the CTE (which you could also join to other tables, etc.).  Of course, in part that's because your "inner" subqueries were a pretty horrible way of doing things; instead, I use `count(distinct sg.id)`, which achieves the same thing as those subqueries as long as `person.id` is non-null, which I presume it is on account of being a PK.

But note also that even the need for a distinct count (and the bugginess of the third part of the query) arise from trying to do all four parts with the same common intermediate results in the first place.  You don't need to join course or grade information in order to query information related strictly to personal characteristics, and as long as student has a 0,1:1 relationship with person, leaving out the course and grade information would give you a distinct count for free.

And as for the third part, joining the `student` table restricts your results to students, which you didn't want.  The fact that you don't put that restriction in the "inner" subquery is irrelevant; you're using that subquery to filter results that only include people who are students in the first place.  Thus, *your approach cannot produce the results you want in this case.**

Maybe your desire to factor out a big chunk of common query arises from the mysterious "other complex code".  I don't see how such a thing applies to the question as you've presented it, but I'm inclined to suspect that you would be better off finding a way -- or maybe separate ways per item -- to simplify or eliminate that code.  If it were the case that that code could be ignored then I might write your query like so:

```
WITH student_person AS (
 SELECT
   p.lastname AS lastname,
   p.age AS age,
   p.gender AS gender,
   s.id AS student_id
 FROM
   PERSON p
   JOIN STUDENT s ON p.ID = s.PERSON_ID
)

-- 1st entry: Number of students on the last name 'E'
SELECT
  'Last names beginning with letter "E"' AS Description,
  count(*) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_person sp1
WHERE sp1.lastname LIKE 'E%'

UNION ALL

-- 2nd entry: Number of students older than 20 years
SELECT
  'Older than 20 years' AS Description,
  count(*) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_person sp2
WHERE sp2.AGE > 20

UNION ALL

-- 3rd entry: Number of female persons, including but not limited to students
-- NOTE: THIS ONE MATCHES YOUR ORIGINAL, WHICH IS INCORRECT
SELECT
  'All female persons' AS Description,
  count(*) AS Number_of_students
-- must select from PERSON, not STUDENT_PERSON:
FROM person p2
WHERE p2.GENDER = 'Female'

UNION ALL

-- 4th entry: Students who passed the course "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade B or higher
SELECT
  'Passed "Intermediate Norwegian" with grade >= B' AS Description,
  count(distinct sp3.student_id) AS Number_of_students
FROM student_person sp3
JOIN grades g ON sp3.student_id = g.student_id
JOIN course c ON g.course_id = c.id
WHERE
  c.COURSE_NAME = 'Intermediate Norwegian'
  AND g.grade IN ('A', 'B')
```

Comment: Huge improvement. The real code is property of my job, so I could never have shown it to you. But I can tell you that the number of lines has been reduced by about 55, from 125 to 70.

I didn't know that it was possible to combine CTEs with further WHERE/JOIN-clauses, and this solves my needs. Thank you :)

Comment: My pleasure.  And FWIW, a CTE is essentially a localized view, so pretty much anything you can do with a (non-materialized) view, you can do with a CTE.

Answer (score 0):

Take it from here, I'm sure you'll manage.

```
select      count(case when lastname like 'e%' then 1 end)  as lastname_starts_with_e
           ,count(case when age > 20           then 1 end)  as age_greater_than_20
           ,count(case when gender = 'Female'  then 1 end)  as is_female

from        person
;
```